# power factor of a dc machine

Tags: electric-machine

To some this might be a weird question, But I am really confused about the definition of reactive power(of what I know, I think it is used to create magnetic flux)..
If am correct, then how is the power factor of a DC machine unity,when it also requires some current to maintain flux across electromagnets.

(A beginner in field of machines)..

Comment: Reactive power is used to *change* magnetic flux ... to *maintain* it you need current, which in conjunction with coil resistance, takes *real* power.

Answer (score 1):

The thing about DC machines is .. they draw DC (ish) current from a DC bus. The concept of PowerFactor doesn't really exist for DC networks

Within the DC machine however, there is actually AC and yes there will be a powerfactor associated with the magnetic circuit

Comment: +1. When you look at the current flow and power draw from the DC source, it never has an opportunity to change direction, so reactive stuff is effectively concealed. Reactive draws get resolved into DC current and it can be considered like apparent power, in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

If we disregard where the DC comes from, lets say a battery, and we disregard the fact that the current taken by the motor is in lumps (via the commutator) then there is no power factor to consider what so ever.

Power factor (PF) is a concept from AC theory. Due to the AC voltage (a sine wave) causing a current to flow in an AC motor winding (which has inductance) then as the inductance tries to delay the change in current flow, and simultaneously the applied AC voltage is changing, we get the AC effect where the current flow through the inductor lags the AC voltage applied across the inductor.

As the sine wave is constantly running (rotating) at say, 50 or 60 Hz, the current lags the voltage by a number of degrees.

A bit of trig and cosines converts this number of degrees lag into a power factor.

Without AC, there is no effective power factor.

You could be asking about changes to current due to commutation, but if so, that I would say is an odd request.

Comment: Its not odd at all. When a commutated segment gets connected the magnetic field must charge in that direction. Its just all very transient and we learn to model it as a lumped system with certain loss characteristics, simply because that is easier.